# RoR - problem with deleting from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a RoR project, I have three models - Person, Event and Attendance. My idea is that multiple people are able to attend multiple events through another model- attendance.

This is my show.html.erb file where I want to display the full information about a specific person, which includes username and events to attend (also a delete button next to each event).

[image: 1]

Since I am new to doing this, I can't figure out how to delete the selected event ONLY for that specific person. Right now if I click on the event-delete button, the event itself will get wiped out from the database, which shouldnt happen because if a user doesn't want to attend a specific event, the connection should be broken only between the user and the event

---

This is not related to the issue anymore, but right now I also can't think of a proper/quality way to add events for a user, so I will appreciate some help for this as well

---

Model relationship
[image: 2]

Comment: can you upload your model relationship / your code that has delete button

Comment: alright, it's uploaded

Comment: i think the title is pretty bad, I apologise for that

Comment: please do not use ref image, we cannot see all the image, just copy / paste code as text (easier)

Comment: Please show your code (by copy and pasting into your question).

Comment: Then edit the title, don’t apologize.

Comment: Fixed images ^^

Comment: Sounds like the attendance record is what "joins" the two.  So the attendance record is actually what you want to delete, right?  So you would need to delete the attendance record with the corresponding `user_id` and `event_id`.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Why are you posting images of plaintext code? Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Well i got to admit I don't really use stack overflow regularly. The code as image looks way better than in plain-text. Also, it doesn't look like a complex issue that needs a lot of testing, at least to me plus I've already explained where the problem is. Though, i will make sure to upload the code as plain-text in the future, sorry

Comment: The code as an image looks way worse than in plaintext, for myriad reasons explained in the link in my previous comment. Even though you've already gotten the answer to your question you should still replace the images in this question with plaintext code, again for the reasons explained in the link.

Comment: Also, please edit the title to make this post properly discoverable. There's a detailed explanation of what makes a good title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I tried to edit your title to remove the "RoR - " part (since your post is already tagged with ruby-on-rails, and "RoR" is not a good descriptor), but the site won't let me save the edit because "problem with deleting from database" is auto-identified as too vague. (which is probably why you added "RoR - " to it, to get around the filter that was trying to explain to you what was wrong with your post title)

Comment: Wait do I seriously get negative upvotes just because of the title? I don't see anything wrong with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link with delete action is for event_path(event) - that's why you're deleting the whole event.

Use attendance_path there like this:

```rb
<%= link_to 'Delete', attendance_path(event.attendance_id), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Or similarly (by also changing the code below a little), perhaps it may be more pragmatic to loop through the *attendances* rather than the events directly: `@person.attendances.each do ... `

Comment: This may be a nicer way to write the code if you extend it to show more detail about the attendance itself - e.g. "When did they register to attend? How did they register?  Did they register with guests? Did they go?..."

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've missed that event has multiple attendances. Then probably the best would be to use Tom Lord's solution - looping through attendances directly.

Comment: So if you want to keep your apps current display:

```ruby
<%= @person.attendances.each do |attendance| %>

  <p>

    <%= attendance.event.name %> | <%= attendance.event.created_at %> =| 
<%= link_to 'Delete', attendance, method: :delete %> <br>

  </p>
```

Comment: Have you define that route in ~/config/routes.rb?
In Rails apps you can use `rake routes` (from the terminal) to show you all the define routes.